# Excel: Match 2 Items, Including if Date is Between a Date Span on Multiple Worksheets

Tags: excel, match

I have 2 worksheets:

- Worksheet 1: Member ID, Engagement Date and other data.
- Worksheet 2: Member ID, Policy Begin Date, Policy End Date and other data.

On Worksheet 1, I want to return a policy type name (from Worksheet 2), if Worksheet 1's Member ID matches Worksheet 2's Member ID AND if Worksheet 1 Engagement Date falls between Worksheet 2's Policy Begin and End Date...

The following is the formula I tried and also have attempted extensive research, to no avail:

```
=INDEX('Program Data'!M2:M25671,MATCH(A2:A489&F2>='Program Data'K2&F2<='Program Data'L2,'Program Data'!E2:E25671,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `MATCH` with an `AGGREGATE` that Calculates the `SMALL`est row where the Policy ID and Dates all match up.

So, we want `AGGREGATE(15, 6, <SOME CODE>, 1)` to get the Smallest **non-error** value in a list created by `<SOME CODE>`

The first thing that `<SOME CODE>` will want is the `ROW` we are looking at (minus one, because I see that you are skipping the header row...) which is `ROW(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$25671)-1`

If the Row does not match, we want to either make it massive or make it error (even better, because then it gets completely skipped).  How to do this?  Well, I have the `POWER` function for that.  If you try `POWER(10,999)` you get a `#NUM!` error, because `10^999` is too large a number for Excel.  If you try `POWER(0,999)` you get 0, because `0^anything` is `0`.  So, we'll just add some `POWER` to our `ROW`s to make it error-out when we don't want them.

But, now we need to decide between `10` and `0`.  Fortunately, Logical statements can be treated as Bitwise Multiplication (`True` = `1` and `False` = 0`)

So, `--(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$25671=$A2)` will give us `1` when the First Columns (Member ID) match, `--(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$25671<=$B2)` will make sure that the Policy Start Date is before-or-on the record date, and `--(Sheet2!$C$2:$C$25671>=$B2)` will check the End Date.  Multiply it all together, and we get `1` when the row matches, and `0` when it doesn't.

Now, if we take that away from `1`, we get the opposite:  `0` when we want `0`, and `1` when we want `10`.  So multiply *that* by 10, and shove it in the `POWER` function, and add that to the `ROW` to get `<SOME CODE>`.  Dump it all in the `AGGREGATE` from the start, and *voila*

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$25671)-1+(POWER(10*(1-(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$25671=$A2)*--(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$25671<=$B2)*--(Sheet2!$C$2:$C$25671>=$B2)),999)),1)
```

Then, just use that in place of your `MATCH` (it will generate a `#NUM!` error when no policy is found)

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!M2:M25671,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$25671)-1+(POWER(10*(1-(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$25671=$A2)*--(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$25671<=$B2)*--(Sheet2!$C$2:$C$25671>=$B2)),999)),1),1)
```

Comment: Impressive!  I am trying to tease out what you have written...but am a little lost as to where sheet 1 comes in.  I would assume it's AGGREGATE (15,6,ROW(Sheet 1...).  My Member IDs are not all numbers, they have letters in side a few of them, too.  Like I said, still teasing this out.

Comment: @user9539580 The Comparison of IDs is done in `(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$25671=$A2)`, so having numbers is no issue. - I written the code assuming that it will be run on `Sheet1`, hence no sheet qualifier on `$A2`